# Concatenating string with variable in Javascript not working properly on Sencha Touch framework

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In my Sencha Touch 2 application, I have a dataview that I populate with elements from a JSONP proxy. My proxy code is as follows:

```
proxy:
{
type: 'jsonp',
url: MyApp.util.Config.getBaseUrl() +
         '/getStatus.php?sid=' + MyApp.util.Config.getSid(),
    reader:
    {
    type: 'json',
    rootProperty: 'element'
    }
  }
}
```

I am declaring some global variables in the Config.js file. When I call `MyApp.util.Config.getBaseUrl() + /getStatus.php?sid=123` with a hard coded `sid`, things work as expected. However if I try to get the global variable `sid` and append it to `/getStatus.php?sid=`, it returns as if `sid` was blank. I am populating the global variable in my app.js file, and I print it to the console after setting it to make sure its filled, and sure enough it seems like it is working.

How can I call the url with a valid `sid`? Is there something wrong with the way I am appending it?

**EDIT  - Full code after attempting answer:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.DashboardView',
{
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
    xtype: 'dashboardview',
    requires: 'MyApp.util.Config',
    config:
    {
        xtype: 'dataview',
        itemId: "dvitem",
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        itemTpl: [ /* some stuff goes here */ ],
        emptyText: 'More Stuff here',
        listeners:
        {
            element: 'element',
            delegate: '#statusbtn',
            tap: function (item, idx, el, evt)
            {
                // gets the item you tapped
                btnId = el.getAttribute('uniqueId');
                alert("hello " + btnId);
            }
        },

        store:
        {
            autoLoad: true,

            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'sid',
                    type: 'int'
                },
                {
                    name: 'user',
                    type: 'int'
                },
                {
                    name: 'from',
                    type: 'string'
                },
                {
                    name: 'to',
                    type: 'string'
                }

            ],

            proxy:
            {
                type: 'jsonp',
                //url: MyApp.util.Config.getBaseUrl() + '/gettatus.php?sid='+MyApp.util.Config.getSid(),
                reader:
                {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'element'
                }
            }
        }

    }

},
function ()
{
    //I think I need to setSid here before. In the meantime, this doesn't work.

    this.prototype.proxy.url = MyApp.util.Config.getBaseUrl() +
        '/getStatus.php?sid=' + MyApp.util.Config.getSid();
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working was using a custom proxy class:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.proxy.MyCustomProxy',
{
extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
alias: 'proxy.mycustomproxy',
buildUrl: function (request)
{
    url = MyApp.util.Config.getBaseUrl() + '/getstatus.php';
    var loginDetails = Ext.getStore('LoginStore');
    loginDetails.load();
    var userId = loginDetails.getAt(0).get('id');
    if (userId != null)
    {
        url = Ext.urlAppend(url, 'uid=' + userId);
    }
    return url;
}
});
```

and I call this proxy instead of a regular JSONP proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This code where you're calling `MyApp.util.Config.getSid()` is probably executed before any application's initialization code. At the time you test it in the console, the initialization, of the config specially, has been executed.

Think about what happens. First, every javascript file is loaded and executed once, top to bottom. Once this is done, any function registered with `Ext.onReady` is called, and your application instance is initialized and created. But your call to `MyApp.util.Config.getSid()` is **not in the body of a function**, so it is called as soon as the containing file is loaded, before Ext really initializes.

One solution could be to set this url in the post-create function of the class where you're using this proxy. But you still need to ensure that the config initialization code has executed before this point.

You can do that by putting your config into a singleton with few dependencies. For example:

```
Ext.define('My.Config', {
    singleton: true
    ,config: {
        sid: '123'
    }
    ,constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
    }
});
```

Then, you can require this config singleton in your other classes. That will ensure that the singleton class is available in the post-create function, where you can finish your proxy's configuration. Continuing with our previous example:

```
Ext.define('My.Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
    ,requires: [
        'My.Config'
    ]
    ,config: {
        fields: ['id','name']
    }
}, function(Cls) {
    Cls.setProxy({
        type: 'jsonp'
        ,url: '/myurl'
    });
});
```

Another option would be to override the [`getUrl`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/source/Server.html#Ext-data-proxy-Server-method-getUrl) method of the proxy, to read the SID just in time. There are plenty of other possibilities but I think these two are the more straightforward and the least surprising (that is, good for code maintainability).

**Update** A solution that should work with your code...

I gave a closer look to your code, I was still on my initial idea that you was defining a model or something... Anyway, in your case the above approach isn't enough, because the store is not a static member of the dataview class. So you'll have to set this configuration when once the class is instantiated. I suggest overriding the `initialize` method of the component, that is specially designed for this kind of "late binding". However, there's no need to create a new instance of the proxy for each new view instance... So I'll create it once in the post-create function, where we'll have access to your config singleton, and tie this instance to the store when it's time.

The following code should be working for you. My changes are that I create the proxy in the post-create function (while yours was creating one per view instance), and attach it to the store in the `initialize` method.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.DashboardView',
{
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
    xtype: 'dashboardview',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.util.Config',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'
    ],
    config:
    {
        xtype: 'dataview',
        itemId: "dvitem",
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        itemTpl: [ /* some stuff goes here */ ],
        emptyText: 'More Stuff here',
        listeners:
        {
            element: 'element',
            delegate: '#statusbtn',
            tap: function (item, idx, el, evt)
            {
                // gets the item you tapped
                btnId = el.getAttribute('uniqueId');
                alert("hello " + btnId);
            }
        },

        store:
        {
            autoLoad: true,

            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'sid',
                    type: 'int'
                },
                {
                    name: 'user',
                    type: 'int'
                },
                {
                    name: 'from',
                    type: 'string'
                },
                {
                    name: 'to',
                    type: 'string'
                }

            ]
        }
    }

    ,initialize: function() {
        this.getStore().setProxy(this.proxy);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

}, function() {
    // Store it in the prototype
    this.prototype.proxy = new Ext.data.proxy.JsonP({
        url: MyApp.util.Config.getBaseUrl() 
                + '/gettatus.php?sid='
                + MyApp.util.Config.getSid(),
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'element'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I am calling `Config.setSid` in the app.js file because I assumed that particular file ran before everything else. Is that not a safe assumption? What I think I should do is set it in the value of `sid` in the post-create function and then set the proxy url as you have suggested. I followed your example and it keeps throwing errors telling me it isn't expecting the `(` symbol on the line where I have `function() {`. How can I properly set up a post-create function?

Comment: Not a safe assumption indeed. The way Javascript works makes it impossible for Ext to know what's in your file before letting it be executed. That could only be resolved server-side, and as far as I'm concerned, I would have cried blood if I had to compile Javascript with a machine-dependent stack. Sencha Cmd is already far too much overhead to my own tastes!... Anyway, I've double-checked my code and there's no such error in it. Can you show me yours?

Comment: I've added the code to the OP. The error I'm getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'url' of undefined` on the line where I have the function you mentioned in your answer. This code is in a bigger file with other things as well (I know its not MVC and all that, but this particular part of the app was done quick and dirty to see if it would work. I plan on reorganizing after I get this working since the rest of the app follows MVC).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I keep forgetting about this Touch `config` object we don't  have in Ext :( In you case the line should then be `this.prototype.config.proxy` but I have no idea of the order in which things are initialized, so I doubt it will work, I wouldn't rely on that. I think you'd better use [setProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-setProxy). It's static so you can do it in the post-create function. I'm updating my answer to reflect that...

Comment: I got the same error making that change. I'll modify my code in accordance with your updated answer and post back.

Comment: Would I remove my other proxy implemenation? When I add the code as you have it with my URL I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line that has `Cls.setProxy({`.

Comment: Sorry again, I missed the fact that your proxy wasn't attached to a static member... This new code should work, from what I could test in a quick fiddle (thanks for providing a working example with almost no dependencies, that really helps) :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47714/discussion-between-amru-e-and-rixo)